# Elixir Ecto Phoenix - Comparing string date format "YYYY-MM-DD" with #DateTime<2017-12-01 13:31:14.987000Z>

Tags: date, datetime, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm trying to implement a date range in my Ecto query where the date ranges are string dates of format `"YYYY-MM-DD"`, and the corresponding created_at date in the database is in `#DateTime<2017-12-01 13:31:14.987000Z>` format.

I have my range comparison query set up, my only problem is in figuring out how to cast my date strings into the same #DateTime format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DateTime.from_iso8601/1](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DateTime.html#from_iso8601/2)

```
date = "2015-01-23"
case DateTime.from_iso8601("#{date}T00:00:00Z") do
    {:error, error} -> error
    {:ok, dt} -> 
                 # .... do stuff 
end
```

If you have the need to manipulate Dates & Times, format, parse & etc, you might look into [Timex](https://hexdocs.pm/timex/getting-started.html) as it covers a lot of usual things related to Dates and Time.

Comment: This doesn't address casting an array of strings in an ecto query tho

Comment: @AlxVallejo indeed, I have to send my magic ball back for a refund. I was trying to answer this: `...my only problem is in figuring out how to cast my date strings into the same #DateTime format` only. I was under the assumption the range in the question just meant, I have a start and end date as strings. Anyway, probably the best approach is, don't, and just use a fragment and the db own date casting/formatting functions inside the query? Hard to say...